# Can we define class in Model:PageModel level by for loop in Asp.net core 6.0 ef?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core-6.0

I had a page which let user to add input field (max 10) by Javascript if they want. Thus, I made a object class call "Items_PC" and define "Items_PC1" to "Items_PC10" for asp-for="" usage.

It is ok when the max number is 10, but i need to manually define it 100 times if the max number is 100, i don't think it is a smart way to do that and the coding is very ugly. Is there any method to define it by for loop?

i use javascript to add the input field:

```
var item = 1;
divtest.innerHTML = ... + 'asp-for"Items_PC' + item + '.model"' + ...
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model KelseyWeb.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}

<form id="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <select id="mySelect" name="values" style="width:95%; height:30px" class=" ms-3">
        <option>Desktop/Notebook</option>
        <option>Monitor</option>
        <option>Others</option>
    </select>
    <input class="" style="width:90px; float:right; font-size:15px" type="button" onclick="add_RequestedItems_fields();" value="Add More" />
    <div class="mb-3" id="1_RequestedItems_fileds">

    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        var item = 0;

        function add_RequestedItems_fields() {
            if(item <10){
                item++;
                var objTo = document.getElementById('1_RequestedItems_fileds')
                var divtest = document.createElement("div");
                if (document.getElementById("mySelect").value.toString() == "Desktop/Notebook") {
                    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="border mt-3 py-3 pe-3" style="display:block">' +
                                            '<input type="text" asp-for="Items_PC' + item + '.Model" value="Desktop/Notebook"/>'+
                                    '</div>';
                }
            }
            objTo.appendChild(divtest)
         }
    </script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
namespace KelseyWeb.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public Items_PC Items_PC1 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC2 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC3 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC4 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC5 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC6 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC7 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC8 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC9 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC10 { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }


    public class Items_PC
    {
        public int Unit { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Spec { get; set; } = null!;
        public string WindowsVersion { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Warranty { get; set; } = null!;
    }



    public class Items_Monitor
    {
        public int Unit { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Warranty { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Items_Others
    {
        public int Unit { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Spec { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

I tried to use for loop and Error - CS1519  Invalid token 'for' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration is received.

I want the code to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify the properties in your page model:

```
 public Items_PC Items_PC1 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC2 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC3 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC4 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC5 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC6 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC7 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC8 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC9 { get; set; }
        public Items_PC Items_PC10 { get; set; }
```

To

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Items_PC> Items_PCs { get; set; }
```

generate the input boxes without asp-xx attribute:

```
 <input type="text" id="Items_PCs[0].Unit" name="Items_PCs[0].Unit/>
   ......
    //other properties you need to insert
```